# Conditional import of React Native library

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to import a React Native library for Android only, as there is no iOS version.

I have the current setup (I used `require` to get around import restrictions):

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  BackgroundColor = require('react-native-background-color');
}
```

But this still fails out on iOS.

Is there a standard way to do this? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: How about importing it and then doing what you need to do using `if(Platform.OS === android) { ... }`?

Comment: It throws an error on import as the code does not exist for iOS

Comment: Well looking at the library's README (https://github.com/ramilushev/react-native-background-color) it looks like they suggest a workaround for iOS. Have you tried that?

Comment: I’ll take a look

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to add a screenshot of the error you are getting on iOS.

Comment: @romin21 - that workaround is to actually set a background color in iOS. I don't care about that and don't need that feature. I need it to not throw an error on iOS - I don't care about the functionality. My issue that requires this is Android-specific. As for the error message, I'll get that up to you later today.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been already fixed by one of the PR (https://github.com/ramilushev/react-native-background-color/pull/8) which has been merged. but, owner of the library has not published the new version.
So, until new version is released, as a workaround you can manually add blank `index.ios.js` file in `node_modules/react-native-background-color/` directory to resolve your import issue in ios. Alternatively you can fork the library.